# Private enums and static fields in the enclosing class

Tags: java, enums, static

I understand why an enum constructor cannot access static fields
and methods within the enum itself, and why the same is allowed
for in classes. Se for an example the following code,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public enum Foo {
    A("Some string"),
    B("Some other string"),
    ;

    static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Foo(String description) {
        list.add(description);
    }
}
```

This code causes a compile-time error, `illegal reference to static field from initializer`.

## Relevant background

The enum constructor is called before the static fields have all
been initialized. In the above example this means that `list` is not yet initialized. This is because static fields are initialized in textual
order [(section 12.4.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static
>   initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the
>   interface, in **textual order**, as though they were a single block.

(emphasis mine)

and since the enum values themselves always precede any other
fields, including static fields, they are not available to the
enum constructor, i.e. no static fields may preceed the enum
values `A`, and `B`.

## Question

However, and here is my question, why is it that a "private" (enclosed inside a class) `enum`
can access static fields of its enclosing class,
regardless of whether or not the enum appears before --- or ---
after the static fields? In particular, where in the Java-specification is this specified?

See the below code for reference

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Bar {
    static List<String> first = new ArrayList<>();

    enum Baz {
        A("Some string"),
        B("Some other string"),
        ;


        Baz(String description) {
            // Can access static fields from before the enum
            first.add(description);

            // Can access static fields from _after_ the enum
            second.add(description);
        }
    }

    static List<String> second = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not sure your assumption of constructor being called before static fields initialization is correct, though. I think it's rather the opposite. Sort of proof: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407743/enum-based-table-matrix-in-java

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis actually the list of enum constants is more or less a list of objects created using the enum's constructor.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis examples have been provided, thanks. And sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit all over the place in the JLS. The [*When Initialization Occurs* chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) states

> The intent is that a class or interface type has a set of initializers
>   that put it in a consistent state, and that this state is the first
>   state that is observed by other classes. The `static` initializers and
>   class variable initializers are executed in textual order, and may not
>   refer to class variables declared **in the class** whose declarations
>   appear textually after the use, even though these class variables are
>   in scope (§8.3.3). This restriction is designed to detect, at compile
>   time, most circular or otherwise malformed initializations.

That bold snippet refers to the class directly containing the access.

`enum` types are defined in the Java Language Specification, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

> An enum declaration specifies a new enum type, a special kind of class type.

The fields you access in the `Baz` constructor

```
Baz(String description) {
    // Can access static fields from before the enum
    first.add(description);

    // Can access static fields from _after_ the enum
    second.add(description);
}
```

are not *class variables declared **in the class***, the enum type `Baz`. The access is therefore allowed.

We can go even deeper into the [detailed class initialization procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2), which explains that each class (class, interface, enum) is initialized independently. However, we can create an example that sees yet-to-be-initialized values

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Bar();
    }
}

class Bar {
    static Foo foo = Foo.A;
    static Integer max = 42;

    enum Foo {
        A;

        Foo() {
            System.out.println(max);
        }
    }
}
```

This will print `null`. The access to `max` is allowed in the `enum` type's constructor although our program execution reached the access before `max` was initialized. The [JLS warns against this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)

> The fact that initialization code is unrestricted allows examples to
>   be constructed where the value of a class variable can be observed
>   when it still has its initial default value, before its initializing
>   expression is evaluated, but such examples are rare in practice. (Such
>   examples can be also constructed for instance variable initialization
>   (§12.5).) The full power of the Java programming language is available
>   in these initializers; **programmers must exercise some care**.

---

Your original `Foo` example introduces an extra rule, defined in the [chapter on *Enum Body Declarations*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2) .

> It is a compile-time error to reference a static field of an enum type
>   from constructors, instance initializers, or instance variable
>   initializer expressions of the enum type, unless the field is a
>   constant variable (§4.12.4).

That rule blocks your `Foo` snippet from compiling.

[`enum` constants translate to `public static final` fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3). These appear textually first in the `enum` type definition and are therefore initialized first. Their initialization involves the constructor. The rules exists to prevent the constructor from seeing uninitialized values of other class variables that will necessarily be initialized later.

Answer (score 3):

The position of nested classes has no meaning. You can refer to the nested class before (earlier in source text) it is declared, same as you can refer to methods before they are declared.

This is because the nested class is actually an independent class. The enclosing class and the nested class are independently initialized.

So, lets say the neither `Bar` nor `Baz` are initialized.

If some code needs `Bar` then `Bar` will be initialized. `Baz` will not be initialized at that time, since `Bar` does not refer to `Baz`.

If however some code needs `Baz` (none of them initialized yet), then `Baz` initialization begins. When the `Baz` constructor for `A` begins running, `Bar` is still not initialized. The first line then needs `Bar`, and `Bar` initialization begins. `Bar` initialization completes normally, in full, before the `first.add(description)` statement is executed. The second statement can also be executed, because `Bar` is fully initialized.

As you can see, there is no initialization order conflict. `Bar` will be fully initialized, and therefore fully available, for use by the `Baz` constructor.

---

To see the sequence of events, I added some print statements:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar.Baz x = Bar.Baz.A;
    }
}
class Bar {
    static { System.out.println("Bar initializing..."); }
    static List<String> first = new ArrayList<>();

    enum Baz {
        A("Some string"),
        B("Some other string"),
        ;
        static { System.out.println("Baz initializing..."); }


        Baz(String description) {
            System.out.println(getClass() + "." + name() + " in construction...");
            // Can access static fields from before the enum
            first.add(description);

            // Can access static fields from _after_ the enum
            second.add(description);
            System.out.println(getClass() + "." + name() + " constructed...");
        }
        static { System.out.println("Baz initialized..."); }
    }

    static List<String> second = new ArrayList<>();
    static { System.out.println("Bar initialized"); }
}
```

*Output*

```
class Bar$Baz.A in construction...
Bar initializing...
Bar initialized
class Bar$Baz.A constructed...
class Bar$Baz.B in construction...
class Bar$Baz.B constructed...
Baz initializing...
Baz initialized...
```

As you can see, `Bar` will starting initializing once *used* inside the `Baz` constructor, and it will be completely initialized at that time. Therefore it is fully available for `Baz` to use, regardless of source text position.

You can also see that `Baz` static initializers don't run until *after* the enums have been constructed, which is of course why you can't reference static members from the constructor.

Comment: Related: [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom)